# Lua Get Data From Text File

Tags: lua

Hey i have a little question

Text file:

```
scripts {    "example_1",    "example_2" }
```

I have a text file with table scripts. And in my lua file I want to get all scripts thad is in thad table.

I already know how to get the text file.

But I don't know how how to extracts the scripts

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `for script in text:gmatch('%b""') do ..... `

Comment: i responded under my post

Comment: this is not a coding service. read this: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1  and present your own attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function called `scripts` that receives a table and then load your text file with `dofile`.